# How should i migrate my app to use JobScheduler?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

My app uses this classic pattern to schedule periodic tasks:

1. Set an exact alarm via `AlarmManager` (via `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`, since it has to go off even in Doze)
2. Start an `IntentService` from `onReceive()` via `WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService()`
3. Do the work in `onHandleIntent()` and call `WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent()` when finished.

Today i updated the targetSdkVersion to 26 and faced the terrible fact that **`WakefulBroadcastReceiver` is deprecated**.

I went to read API docs immediately and found the following:

> As of Android O, background check restrictions make this class no
>   longer generally useful. (It is generally not safe to start a service
>   from the receipt of a broadcast, because you don't have any guarantees
>   that your app is in the foreground at this point and thus allowed to
>   do so.) Instead, developers should use `android.app.job.JobScheduler` to
>   schedule a job, and this does not require that the app hold a wake
>   lock while doing so (the system will take care of holding a wake lock
>   for the job).

This is kinda confusing to me, i don't really understand what is the purpose of `AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` without being able to keep the device awake anymore.

As i see i cannot set an exact time to run a job with `JobScheduler`, only conditions (such as network type or charging state) so i have no idea what to do here.

I thought of either

- Using `AlarmManager` and `JobScheduler` together

  Set an alarm (with `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`) and start a job (via `JobScheduler`) immediately from `onReceive()`. Since `JobScheduler` provides a `WakeLock`, `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` is not needed.

  (does this make sense?)

or

- Keep using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` despite being deprecated.

I'd really appreciate any advice on this matter.

Comment: have you find nay answer ???

Comment: Now it's preferred to use Jetpack's [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) instead JobScheduler directly. afaik, there's still no method for setting an exact time for Work to be dispatched, so combining `AlarmManger` and `WorkManager.OneTimeWorkRequest` as you alluded to still seems the way to get a task "probably" done at a precise time

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCylj3i5cXI)

Answer (score -1):

In android-o and later you can define a repeating task without alarmmanager like this:

```
// schedule the start of the service "TestJobService" every 10 - 30 minutes
public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
    ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, TestJobService.class);
    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
    builder.setMinimumLatency(10 * 60 * 1000); // wait at least
    builder.setOverrideDeadline(30 * 60 * 1000); // maximum delay
    JobScheduler jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
    jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a BroadcastReciever that is triggered by your Alarm and in that receiver call JobIntentService.enqueueWork with your service, that you'll need to convert to a JobIntentService and implement the onHandleWork method.
The solution is described here:
[Issue Moving from IntentService to JobIntentService for Android O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46675242/issue-moving-from-intentservice-to-jobintentservice-for-android-o)